# Cannot connect to sshd over vpn

Tags: ssh, vpn, centos6, softether

I have a VPS running Centos 6.8 where I installed SoftEther VPN server with a local bridge.

VPN IP range is 192.168.86.0/24. Client VPN IP addresses are provided by SoftEther VPN Server's DHCP server. There is virtual network adapter used for SoftEther's local bridge because I would like to access some services on the VPS through the VPN (in SoftEther this is not possible without local bridge).  VPN default gateway address is 192.168.86.3.

The VPS has a public IPv4 address on eth0 interface, plus I created an alias eth0:0 with IPv4 addr 192.168.86.2 (this is out of the range provided by DHCP of the VPN and differs from VPN's default gateway).

When I connect from Windows PC, everything seems to be right. I can ping both the 192.168.86.3 (which is the SoftEther VPN server's network interface for connected VPN clients) and the 192.168.86.2 (which is out of the VPN server, being a "physical" network interface on VPS).

However, I cannot connect to any service running on VPS via the VPN connection - neither SSH on port 22 (none of the two addresses, .2 nor .3), nor can I connect to a simple web server running as root on port 80 on the VPS (using nodejs).  Direct connections (to the public IPv4 address), however, work.

What exactly did I miss? Should I look into SSHD configuration for the interfaces, or could the problem be in iptables setup, or is it something to be fixed in SELinux?  I am afraid I have no idea where to look for the problem.

The only thing I believe to be sure is that this is not directly related to SoftEther VPN server - before I activated the local bridge function, I could not ping any of the VPN IP addresses except the default gateway, now the local alias 192.168.86.2 became visible and responds to pings.

`ip addr` on VPS returns this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:00:46:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 46.28.111.205/24 brd 46.28.111.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.86.2/24 brd 192.168.86.255 scope global eth0:0
    inet6 2a02:2b88:2:1::4607:1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe00:4607/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tap_tap01: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether 00:ac:56:ec:e5:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::2ac:56ff:feec:e53c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route` on the VPS returns this:

```
192.168.86.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.86.2
46.28.111.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 46.28.111.205
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
default via 46.28.111.1 dev eth0
```

It seems that SoftEther VPN server does not configure a IPv4 address on `tap_tap01` (SoftEther's virtual network interface for the bridge).  Interestingly, it is possible to ping both IPv4 addresses from within VPN session but the VPN network is unreachable/invisible in the VPS.  Which is contrary to what I would expect from the local bridge.

Comment: Please add your networking configuration files and other relevant files to your post. Your description is difficult to read.

Comment: I don't think there are any relevant files beyond what I wrote in the description.

Comment: Can you read something from *ss -l* output?
`State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                                         Local Address:Port                                                             Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      128                                                                       :::ssh                                                                        :::*
LISTEN      0      128                                                                        *:ssh                                                                         *:*
`

Comment: What is the interface that Softether VPN creates? What is Softether VPN configuration? How does it get its IP addresses?

Comment: Well, this is puzzling... Softether VPN creates virtual network interface tap_tap01.  It is visible as network interface, but it has no visible configuration - I did not find any file like /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-tap_tap01.  It seems that VPN server created something in the system but did not finish configuration.  I was trying to read some interent howtos.  Maybe I should just try to create a bridge manually.
However, I remain cautious. Last time I started playing with bridges on a local machine, I lost network connectivity and had to use console to restore the host. Bad on VPS.

Comment: One thing that is clearly wrong with your configuration is that you assign a private network address to a public network interface `eth0`. You have to have a separate network adapter for your VPN network and configure the IP address there.

Comment: Can it be a virtual network adapter? Where to look for documentation, please (what is the config file to be used or system command)?  I was trying to search but the results are not very clear.  All links point to solutions where physical intefaces are aliased.  This is not exactly what I want, I just need some point, other than physical ethernet device, the VPN server could use.  Assuming that the "physical" device eth0 in a VPS is a virtual NIC anyway, I don't undestand why is it so difficult to find any relevant docs in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely find that the httpd/node and sshd etc services are started before the VPN server. In this case, the services will only bind to the interfaces that are available when they start. You will need to configure the system to start the services after the VPN server. You should also ensure that the services are configured to bind to all available addresses.

Comment: They seem to be ok, but for some reason the VPN server's VPN address is unreachable from the operating system.  It is not listed anywhere.  I wonder how ping works: it returns response from 192.168.86.2 but in any other case than ping the two network interfaces 192.168.86.2 and  192.168.86.3 don't seem to "see" each other.